# Registering an Interface with multiple generic types using XML configuration in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I've an interface with two generic types

```cs
public interface IHelloWorldService<T, R>
{
}
```

and this is my implementation

```cs
public class HelloWorldService<T> : IHelloWorldService<T, Domain.DataModel.HelloWorld>
{
}
```

and also this is my configuration file

```
<configuration>
    <components>
        <component
            type="Service.HelloWorldService`1[[T]], Service"
            service="Domain.Service.IHelloWorldService`2[[T], [Domain.DataModel.HelloWorld, Domain]], Domain" />
    </components>
</configuration>
```

As the type of T is supposed to specify by developers, How should I declare T in XML file ?